# RadDatePicker SetDate() not working

Tags: javascript, telerik, rad

I believe I am using version 2008 of RadDatePicker control. After getting reference of the datePicker in JavaScript, I try to set date using SetDate() function. However it gives me "Object doesn't support this propety or method". The current javascript function as shown on telerik website is not present in the control I am using. However I found from the debugger that the datePicker control has a function SetDate(_2c) in it's Methods. I tried giving the following to the SetDate function

```
  datePicker.SetDate('1/1'2012') gives me "Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

If I try the following:

```
      datePicker.SetDate(new Date('1/1/2012')) it gives me undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind have you set the min and max dates?

```
  datePicker.MinDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
  datePicker.MaxDate = new DateTime(2100, 12, 31);
```

And on your client side have you tried:

```
var myDate=new Date();
// set to Jan 1, 2012
//(months are from 0-11 not 1-12)
myDate.setFullYear(2012,0,1);

datePicker.SetDate(myDate);
datePicker.DateInput.SetDate(myDate);
```